# I can't match the sequence between two specific words

Tags: regex

I want to find a string that is between two specific words. See in the picture the pattern I made. The problem is that "INICIO" is appearing twice, I just want it to match it last appearance until the word "FIM". In this case, I wanted the first pattern to be INICIOBBBBBBBBBBBFIM. I need match all occurrence in the string.

[Link to Regex](https://regex101.com/r/lubdJJ/2/)

[My Regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3ppJ.png)

Comment: Please put the examples in the question itself instead of relying on external sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for sounds like what Rexegg terms a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

```
INICIO(?:(?!INICIO).)*?FIM
```

[See your updated demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lubdJJ/3)

The negative lookahead "tempers" the dot to not jump over another start. This practice is rather costly as before each position the lookahead looks ahead if there is no `INICIO` ahead before proceeding.

If interested, [there is a nice answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/5527985) explaining it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
.*(INICIO.*?FIM)
```

or

```
INICIO(?!.*\BINICIO\B)\B.*?\BFIM
```

might be OK to start with.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/w22Yyl/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/w22Yyl/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/f8YZKZ/1/)

Comment: I need match the both sequence. That solution match all string.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the string, and search for

```
 MIF.*?OICINI
```

Then reverse the match

```
 "JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJINICIOAAAAAAAAAAAAINICIOBBBBBBBBBBBBFIMJJJJJJJJJJJJJJINICIOJJJJJJJJJJJJJJFIM"
      .split("")
      .reverse()
      .join("")
      .match(/MIF.*?OICINI/g)[1]
      .split("")
      .reverse()
      .join("");
```

(Notice, I'm actually grabbing the second match here. This is because the matches are in reverse order as well)

Answer (score 0):

A bit contrived but this could work:

```
(?<=INICIO).*?(INICIO.*?FIM)|(?<=FIM).*?(INICIO.*?FIM)
```

Your result will be in `$2`

https://regex101.com/r/qUf4kE/1